# How to change (jailbroken) iOS proxy settings via command line?

Tags: ios, networking, configuration, settings, jailbreak

When testing iOS app through external proxy, I find it inconvenient to switch proxy settings on and off (Settings -> WiFi -> .... -> HTTP PROXY). Moreover, turning proxy off wipes Server/Port settings so they need to be configured again when enabling proxy back.

I would like to have a small shell script that will just enable/disable proxy, so I could switch it with just one command via SSH.

Any hints where the network and proxy configuration is stored in the filesystem? Any command line utilities capable of modifying it?

Answer (score 3):

The network proxy preferences are stored (at least in iOS 8) in 
`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`.

This property list file can be modified using the command line tool `plutil` (included in the "Erica Utilities" package available in Cydia).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the proxy settings from

```
/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

make sure restarting the phone it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use my tweak [here](https://github.com/karajanyp/iOS-ProxyTool).

All you need is a jailbroken device.The usage is simple:

to set proxy: proxytool 1 10.80.8.103 8888

to clear proxy: proxytool 0

You can download the code and MAKE by yourself, or you can just download the release package and install it to your device.

Hope this helps.